# Ajax/post request on an incremented id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input, delete-file

I'm generating custom fields for images, text and other kind and you can delete these fields with javascript. But now, when I delete an image field I need to delete the image file in a folder as well.

Here's what my field look like :

```
<input type='hidden' id='img_dlt_".$row2->rank."' name='img' value='".$row2->content."'/>
<div id='deletebtn'>delete this</div>
```

the ID has a number incremented. When I presse "deletebtn" div I need to make an Ajax request to tell PHP, thanks to the input "value", to delete the file in a folder

So I've tried this :

```
$("#deletebtn").live("click", function(){
      $(this).parent("li").remove();

      var img_to_delete = $("my_field_id").val();

      $.ajax({ 
          url : "/mysite/admin/delete_img_function",
          type : 'POST',
          data : img_to_delete,
          complete: function(success){
               alert(img_to_delete);
          },
      });
```

But it doesn't work because I have many image field and I need to delete a specific one, and I don't know how to retrieve the specific incremented ID of the field which I'm trying to delete

Any help would be very very appreciated !

Comment: how do you select the images to be deleted? do they have checkboxes?

Comment: No the image name is in the value of an hidden field which I need to retrieve to delete it with PHP

Answer (score 1):

your code has 2 problems, 
1.  as you are retrieving value by the hidden field's id you must use # $("#my_field_id") instead of $("my_field_id"). 

2. as you want to post a form data, the data must have a name that you can retrieve it with php. here in the edited code, I name it id:

```
$("#deletebtn").live("click", function(){
      $(this).parent("li").remove();

      var img_to_delete = $("#my_field_id").val();

      $.ajax({ 
          url : "/mysite/admin/delete_img_function",
          type : 'POST',
          data : {id: img_to_delete},
          complete: function(success){
               alert(img_to_delete);
          },
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of ajax calling is incorrect,
consider this :-

```
data : {id:img_to_delete},
```

From the docs :- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

At the PHP /mysite/admin/delete_img_function,
you can then refer to `$_POST[id]`

Comment: Maybe it's not correct but I just want to retrieve the "value" of an hidden field and transmit it to PHP through ajax not the id

Comment: no, you did not assign a proper $_POST[$key], and PHP not able to render